# error create database in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

```
sudo php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 125:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  could not find driver


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

please help .

Comment: Have you installed `pdo_mysql`, or whatever are you using?

Comment: Run `composer install` and check if PDO driver is in installed

Comment: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install --symlink --relative public [OK]                                                                                                                      result if I check composer install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension.

If you are on a Windows machine look in your `php.ini` file and uncomment `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`. The path to your `php.ini` file can be found by looking at your `phpinfo()`.

Debian/Ubuntu

PHP 5 `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

PHP 7 `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

You will then need to ensure the module is enabled:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: error :   sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet php7.0-mysql
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « php7.0-mysql »
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « php7.0-mysql »

Comment: You must translate the output. Show the output of the following command: `php -v`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your php.ini file has the lines :

```
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=mysqli
```

Comment: From next time onwards, use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).